# How to replace ideographic space in PHP string?

Tags: php

ideographic space is http://www.charbase.com/3000-unicode-ideographic-space, it is a CJK punctuation. It looks like a normal space but it actually takes 2 positions in screen instead of 1(like a Chinese character would do)

I tried using `str_replace(" ","",$mystring)` to get rid of them, but of course it doesn't work, because the space I input here is an ASCII space. I also tried manually input the ideographic space using Chinese character input method, but it looks like this way I will also get rid of part of other characters' code and it returns gibberish.

So how can I get rid of these spaces?

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo .. sorry, nope. Try: `php -r 'print trim(html_entity_decode("&#x3000;a")) . "\n";'` .. And the [documentation for `trim()`](http://php.net/trim) clearly lists the characters it considers to be whitespace, and 0x3000 is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replace the character just fine by copying the symbol from the informational page you linked to. You might want to create a `CONST` alias for the ideographic space just to help make and find/replace coding more clear.

```
// contains ideographic space between words
$start = 'before　after';                    

// contains ideographic space in needle parameter
$test1 = str_replace('　', '_', $start);     

// contains ideographic space
define('ID_SPACE', '　');                    
$test2 = str_replace(ID_SPACE, '&', $start);

// contains normal space in needle parameter
$test3 = str_replace(' ','_',$start);       

// make sure we are using utf8 for this test
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo $start.'<br/>';
echo $test1.'<br/>';
echo $test2.'<br/>';
echo $test3;
```

output:

```
before　after
before_after
before&after
before　after
```

**Edit in response to question**

While you cannot see it, the character is being displayed in the box shown, just click-drag to select like you would any other text, and then you can paste it as needed. You can also just copy the code from my answer which contains the space. If you see something like `ã€€` then you need to set your charset to utf-8

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert things from their escaped numeric values directly.  I've had the following function sitting around for years. I didn't write it, and I'm afraid I don't recall where I found it.  It's a bit of a hack, but a damn useful one I think.

```
<?php

function code2utf($num) {
  if($num<128)return chr($num);
  if($num<2048)return chr(($num>>6)+192).chr(($num&63)+128);
  if($num<65536)return chr(($num>>12)+224).chr((($num>>6)&63)+128).chr(($num&63)+128);
  if($num<2097152)return chr(($num>>18)+240).chr((($num>>12)&63)+128).chr((($num>>6)&63)+128).chr(($num&63)+128);
  return '';
}

print "a" . code2utf(0x3000) . "b" . code2utf(0x1f44d) . "\n";
```

And when I run this, I see:

```
$ php -f utftest
a　b
```

Note that the what looks like two spaces is a single double-width character.

Perhaps you can use the above function to construct your input string, like this:

```
str_replace(code2utf(0x3000),"",$mystring);
```

The obvious advantage of a solution like this over WebChemist's copy-and-paste solution is that it's entirely programmatic, and does not require any special functions as part of the programmer's tools. You will not accidentally overwrite the ID_SPACE character when reformatting your code, and the function is reusable for other UTF8 characters you might need to represent, without the need to actually have those characters within your code.

---

Of course, the other way you could do this is with the built-in PHP function [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).  The following produces results identical to my function, using HTML escaped characters as input:

```
$ php -r 'print html_entity_decode("a&#x3000;b&#x1f44d;") . "\n";'
a　b
```

Answer (score 0):

A method that also worked for me, raw encoding it into HTML Entities & `str_replace` back to a normal whitespace.

```
//The space we're looking out for
$ideoSpace      = "%26%23x3000%3B";
$space          = "%20";

//Search string (Notice the wider space)
$searchstr = "Please find me a Oil　Filter";

//Begin conversion
$searchstr = rawurldecode( str_replace( $ideoSpace, $space, rawurlencode( $searchstr )));

//echos "Please find me a Oil Filter"
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution. However unfortunately the search was not working for us, as `implode()` was not able to split the strings for our Japanese customers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function fixSpaceProblem($string) {

    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    $hasBugString = (mb_split('[[:space:]]', $string));
    $fixedString = join(" ",$hasBugString);

    return $fixedString;
}
```

I use it for myself and it works.